# How to find which SQLite pragmas take effect during SQL compilations?

Tags: sqlite

According to [the docs](https://www.sqlite.org/pragma.html),

> Some pragmas take effect during the SQL compilation stage, not the execution stage. This means if using the C-language sqlite3_prepare(), sqlite3_step(), sqlite3_finalize() API (or similar in a wrapper interface), the pragma may run during the sqlite3_prepare() call, not during the sqlite3_step() call as normal SQL statements do. Or the pragma might run during sqlite3_step() just like normal SQL statements. Whether or not the pragma runs during sqlite3_prepare() or sqlite3_step() depends on the pragma and on the specific release of SQLite.

Information in the last statement isn't given in documentation for specific pragmas. Assuming I am nonetheless interested in finding it, presumably I have to look at the source. But where exactly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All pragmas that are [implemented by the underlying VFS](http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/c_fcntl_busyhandler.html#sqlitefcntlpragma) are executed while parsing.
(But none of the predefined pragmas are implemented in the VFS.)

Otherwise, the easiest way to find out is to [look](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_explain.html) at the generated [virtual machine instructions](http://www.sqlite.org/opcode.html) of the pragma.
Some pragmas do not do anything in the VDBE code, which implies that they were completely executed while parsing (and the EXPLAIN does not prevent that):

```
> EXPLAIN PRAGMA page_size = 16384;
addr  opcode         p1    p2    p3    p4             p5  comment      
----  -------------  ----  ----  ----  -------------  --  -------------
0     Init           0     1     0                    00  Start at 1   
1     Halt           0     0     0                    00
```

But note that unknown pragmas are simply ignored:

```
> EXPLAIN PRAGMA give_me_lots_of_money;
addr  opcode         p1    p2    p3    p4             p5  comment      
----  -------------  ----  ----  ----  -------------  --  -------------
0     Init           0     1     0                    00  Start at 1   
1     Halt           0     0     0                    00
```

Many pragmas that simply return a value generate code with the current value at parsing time:

```
> EXPLAIN PRAGMA page_size;
addr  opcode         p1    p2    p3    p4             p5  comment      
----  -------------  ----  ----  ----  -------------  --  -------------
0     Init           0     1     0                    00  Start at 1   
1     Int64          0     1     0     16384          00  r[1]=16384   
2     ResultRow      1     1     0                    00  output=r[1]  
3     Halt           0     0     0                    00
```

But some pragmas look up the value when they are executed:

```
> EXPLAIN PRAGMA user_version;
addr  opcode         p1    p2    p3    p4             p5  comment      
----  -------------  ----  ----  ----  -------------  --  -------------
0     Init           0     1     0                    00  Start at 1   
1     Transaction    0     0     0                    00               
2     ReadCookie     0     1     6                    00               
3     ResultRow      1     1     0                    00  output=r[1]  
4     Halt           0     0     0                    00
```

And some pragmas can be implemented with VDBE code:

```
> EXPLAIN PRAGMA foreign_key_check;
addr  opcode         p1    p2    p3    p4             p5  comment      
----  -------------  ----  ----  ----  -------------  --  -------------
0     Init           0     15    0                    00  Start at 15  
1     OpenRead       0     2     0     2              00  root=2 iDb=0; MyTable
2     String8        0     3     0     MyTable        00  r[3]='MyTable'
3     OpenRead       1     3     0     k(2,,)         00  root=3 iDb=0 
4     Rewind         0     14    0                    00               
5       Column         0     1     8                    00  r[8]=MyTable.Parent
6       IsNull         8     13    0                    00  if r[8]==NULL goto 13
7       MakeRecord     8     1     7     A              00  r[7]=mkrec(r[8])
8       Found          1     13    7     0              00  key=r[7]     
9       Rowid          0     4     0                    00  r[4]=rowid   
10      String8        0     5     0     MyTable        00  r[5]='MyTable'
11      Integer        0     6     0                    00  r[6]=0       
12      ResultRow      3     4     0                    00  output=r[3..6]
13    Next           0     5     0                    00               
14    Halt           0     0     0                    00               
15    Transaction    0     0     3     0              01  usesStmtJournal=0
16    Goto           0     1     0                    00
```

There are pragmas (e.g., `default_cache_size`) that execute both while parsed and while executed; this is typically for values that are recorded in the database file (such writes can be done only inside a transaction).

So the safest way is to look at the function `sqlite3Pragma` in the `src/pragma.c` file.